# Error deploying Java Spring Boot app on Google App Engine: Timed out fetching pod (Error Response: [4])

Tags: google-cloud-platform, java, google-app-engine, springboot

This is my first time deploying on Google App Engine [or, at least, trying to]. I've built a Java Spring Boot app, configured the `app.yaml` and did the other preparation steps. However, when I run `gcloud app deploy`, I get the following error message:

`ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Timed out fetching pod.`

I'm trying to deploy at the standard environment. The error occurs around 5min into the `Updating service [default]` step. As far as I can tell by the logs, the building was successful. I couldn't find much info about this specific error on the web.

**app.yaml** (/src/main/appengine/app.yaml)

```
runtime: java11

env: standard

instance_class: B1

basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1

env_variables:
  PROFILE: "prod"
  TWILIO_SID: 0
  TWILIO_KEY: 0
  TWILIO_PHONE_FROM: 0
  TWILIO_PHONE_TO: 0
```

Am I missing something? What could I double check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying different scenarios, I ended up discovering that the issue was being caused by the selected region (in my case, `southamerica-east1`). I can't tell if it's something temporary or not, but recreating the project with another region solved it for me.